# How do I disable the fade out/fade in effect when unlocking a Windows 7 workstation?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, animation, visual-effects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to remove the fade effect between login?](https://superuser.com/questions/451221/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-fade-effect-between-login)

When I press Win+L, the “Locked” screen (with the password prompt) appears immediately. That’s nice, but not terribly important: I’m probably leaving the computer anyway.

But after I type the password (to unlock the workstation), the desktop doesn’t appear immediately: instead, the “Locked” screen slowly fades out, the desktop slowly fades in, wasting my time, and all keys (e.g. Win+R) pressed during this interval are completely swallowed, forcing me to wait unnecessarily. This is extremely annoying because when I unlock the workstation, I generally want to use my computer.

How do I disable this fade out/fade in effect and have the desktop appear immediately, in the same way that the “Locked” screen appears immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear to be possible to turn this effect off.

Comment: The effect does not function on my VirtualBox installation of Windows 7 Ultimate. This indicates a possibility of disabling the effect, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Deltik doesn't function on my laptop when using the XP graphics card driver. Using the W7 driver makes it functions, but it has other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

> the desktop slowly fades in

Do you have the fade effect set to something ridiculous? It fades in the desktop in 1 or 2 seconds for me.

You may want to try turning off visual effects.

Comment: I haven’t set it to anything. 1 or 2 seconds is far too long, I’m surprised you’re happy with that. How do I turn it off?

Comment: You can poke around HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI but it doesn't have anything for fade. I have disabled visual effects and it still fades, so I guess this may be something you will have to live with.

Comment: Takes about 1 second for me... eases me gently back into my work  :¬)