# How do I disable the fade out effect when Windows goes into standby?

Tags: windows-7, standby, animation

Is there any way to disable the fade to black effect when Windows enters standby state? I have a tablet PC and when I press the power button I want the screen to turn off immediately, not showing me some silly animation that gives me the impression of being SLOW.

Comment: Which version and edition of Windows?

Comment: Edited the question. Who downvoted me? wth?!

Comment: It was not me, but one of the reasons for downvoting is that it shows no research effort. Perhaps that is the case here.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/149215/how-do-i-disable-the-fade-out-fade-in-effect-when-unlocking-a-windows-7-workstat although that one is about fading in not out, but answer should be the same: not possible.

Comment: I did see that other question (which is similar but about login screen to desktop instead of entering standby). Also I did some research before asking the question but couldn't find anything directly related. Anyway, I expected that there is no easy way to do this.

Comment: I've also been interested in disabling the fade effect. I currently have **UAC** set to "do not dim my desktop".

Comment: This setting only affects whether or not your desktop will be greyed out (=temporarily unresponsive to mouse events) when a UAC prompt pops up.